# Value that matches every possible value (except null of course)?

Tags: sql, postgresql

Is there any trick in postgresql to make a value match every possible value, a kind of "Catch all" value, an anti-NULL ?

Right now, my best idea is to choose a "catchall" keyword and force a match in my queries.

```
WITH cities AS (SELECT * FROM (VALUES('USA','New York'),
                                     ('USA','San Francisco'),
                                     ('Canada','Toronto'),
                                     ('Canada','Quebec')
                               )x(country,city)),
     zones  AS (SELECT * FROM (VALUES('USA East','USA','New York'),
                                     ('USA West','USA','San Francisco'),
                                     ('Canada','Canada','catchall')
                               )x(zone,country,city))
SELECT z.zone, c.country, c.city
FROM cities c,zones z
WHERE c.country=z.country
  AND z.city IN (c.city,'catchall');

   zone   | country |     city
----------+---------+---------------
 USA East | USA     | New York
 USA West | USA     | San Francisco
 Canada   | Canada  | Toronto
 Canada   | Canada  | Quebec
```

If a new canadian town was inserted in the "cities" table, the "zones" table would automatically recognize it as part of the 'Canada' zone.
The above query satisfies the functionality I'm looking for, but it feels awkward and prone to errors if repeated multiple times in a wide database.

Is this the proper way to do it, is there a better way, or am I asking the wrong question ?

Thanks a lot for your answers!

Comment: Not sure if I'm understanding the requirements correctly, but `where c.country=z.country and (z.city in (c.city) or z.city is null);` would put all cities from a particular country in that country's zone with null in the city column (replace 'catchall' with null in the example). However, this would only be useful if you plan to have all cities in a country in the same zone. In your example, if you added a USA zone with a null city, both NYC and SF would end up in the east/west zones and the new null zone.

Comment: Yes, this is also a possibility and you absolutely understood the requirements. I plan to implement this in a database with a lot of similar join queries, and I'm looking for the most elegant solution. I can't help but thinking it would be so great to obtain the result I'm looking for with a simple `select * from cities join zones using(country,city)`.

Comment: A bit more readable (but longer) way to write `catchall`: `(z.city = c.city or z.city = 'catchall')`

Comment: does the simple `whatever IS NOT NULL` do what you want?

Comment: `whatever IS NOT NULL` will make every non-NULL value on the left match every row on the right, so it wouldn't produce the desired result. Here I'm trying to find a value where designated rows on the right match every row on the left.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Personally, I think that `NULL` makes a better choice for this:

```
select z.zone, c.country, c.city
from cities c join
     zones z
     on c.country = z.country and
        (c.city = z.city or z.city is null);
```

or even:

```
select z.zone, c.country, c.city
from cities c join
     zones z
     on c.country = z.country and
        c.city = coalesce(z.city, c.city);
```

As per Denis, Postgres seems to be smart enough to use an index on the first query for both `country` and `city`.

You could also do a two part join, if you have indexes on both `zone(country)` and on `zone(country, city)`, you could do a two part join:

```
select coalesce(zcc.zone, zc.zone) as zone, c.country, c.city
from cities c join
     zones zcc
     on c.country = z.country and
        c.city = z.city join
     zones zc
     on c.country = z.country and
        zc.city is null;
```

Although a bit more complicated, both joins should be able to use appropriate indexes.

Comment: Haven't tasted, but I think Postgres will be able to use index for first query. (`bitmap index scan` and `bitmap or`/`bitmap and`). [`Link`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/indexes-bitmap-scans.html).

Comment: Use of `IS DISTINCT FROM` will simplify some of the above.

Comment: The only problem with using `NULL` is that it also matches NULL values on the left side. So I guess I can use `c.city=z.city or (z.city is null and c.city is not null)`.

Comment: "postgres will not use an index on city for any of these queries" -- it would use a bitmap index scan in the first query, and `OR` the results of two separate index scans as needed.

Comment: For completeness in reply to the comment that got deleted, see http://www.postgresql.org/message-id/12553.1135634231@sss.pgh.pa.us and http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.2/interactive/indexes-bitmap-scans.html

Answer (score 0):

I doubt that there is something like that. A simple way, but not very elegant, efficient or flexible, is to define your function `cities_equals(text t1, text t2)`  which returns true if both are not null and ( t1 == t2 OR t1 == 'catchall' OR t2 == 'catchall')

Answer (score 0):

Change your condition to SIMILAR TO and construct a regex that matches both:

```
  and z.city similar to '(' || c.city || ')|(%)'
```

Comment: This will disable any postgres attempt to use an index on `city` field (it any present).